# Error : Error of failed request: BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation) while rendering rectangles in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, x11, tkinter-canvas

Error of failed request:  BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation)

I wanted to render a good amount of rectangles using tkinter and it worked normally when number of rectangles were 10^6 but when I tried to render it after converting it into an image , it didn't even work for even 2000 rectangles and I got this error:

**X Error of failed request:  BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  53 (X_CreatePixmap)
Serial number of failed request:  15777
Current serial number in output stream:  15788**

Here is the Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageDraw
import time
images = []
def create_rectangle(x,y,a,b, **options):
    if 'alpha' in options:
        # Calculate the alpha transparency for every color(RGB)
        alpha = int(options.pop('alpha') * 255)
        # Use the fill variable to fill the shape with transparent color
        fill = options.pop('fill')
        # fill = window.winfo_rgb(fill) + (alpha,)
        fill = tuple(c // 256 for c in window.winfo_rgb(fill)) + (alpha,)
        image = Image.new('RGBA', (a-x, b-y), fill)
        images.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(image))
        canvas.create_image(x, y, image=images[-1], anchor='nw')

        # optional
        canvas.create_rectangle(x, y,a,b, **options)

# Create the main window
start=time.time()
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Stairs Structure")
canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=1000, height=1000)
canvas.pack()

# Define the dimensions of the rectangles
rect_width = 20
rect_height = 10

# Define the number of stairs and the height of each step
num_stairs = 10000
step_height = 10

# Loop to create the rectangles
for i in range(num_stairs):
    x1 = 0
    y1 = i * step_height
    x2 = (i + 1) * rect_width
    y2 = (i + 1) * step_height

    # Create a rectangle on the canvas
    create_rectangle(x1,y1,x2,y2,fill='grey50',alpha=0.3)

end=time.time()

print("The time of execution is :",(end-start) * 10**3, "ms")
# Start the Tkinter event loop
window.mainloop()
```

I am using a Linux machine. Can someone please tell me what I did wrong here and what this error is all about?
PS: Any other methods to convert the rectangles to images so that's its alpha properties can be enabled is appreciated if you feel like this method is slow and not efficient.

Comment: You have created too many images (10000) which consumes too much memory.  I wonder why you create such big number of images within a window with size 1000x1000.

Comment: I want to test out the performance of this on a larger use case, do you think window size is the issue here?

Comment: No, it does not depend on the size of the window, but the number of images created.  Instead you can create just one image with the number of rectangles created inside that image.

Comment: That won't solve my problem, I want to enable alpha rendering for these rectangles and creating one image wont mean anything, I would rather just create normal rectangles.

Comment: You can still create transparent rectangles inside an image.

Comment: @acw1668 - the tag/binding on each image - i do not think that creating transparent rectangles inside an image will solve bind problem. The op might also be looking for binding each image

Comment: @Vatsalya Goswami. Is this is what is look like? https://imgur.com/a/E5LivZM

Comment: @toyotaSupra yes, it worked for you for num_stairs =10000?

Comment: I got small canvas window. I merely got 50 steps

Comment: I add `canvas` to `canvas.create_rectangle(x1,y1, ....`

Comment: @Vatsalya Goswami. Set to `canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)`. I merely limited on my 4K monitor(28 inch). Remove `alpha=0.3`

Comment: See [ask]. You already know the error was caused by creating too many images. You asked several things, but the only meaningful one is "Any other methods...", and it's too broad or unspecific. Research more and ask a specific question. Anyway, here's my opinion. Use only single image and draw rectangles on the image with the ```ImageDraw.rectangle()```[https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.rectangle], as mentioned by acw1668.

Comment: There exist no other ways.